Is there a way to read data from an amiibo?
Just for the fun of it, is there a way I read (not write) data from an amiibo? I think it would be cool if I could make a mini-game that summons Mario if I put a Mario amiibo. Also, I know I shouldn't write on an amiibo, because I could mess it up completely, but can reading it from something other then a Nintendo device ruin the amiibo data and is it also legal? (This game is obviously not going online. It's just a me thing)

There are Android apps that can read Amiibo data, so it is possible. You can try using the JavaScript NDEFReader API to scan an Amiibo and see what you're able to read. What specific help do you need from us? Obviously, putting Mario in your game is not legal outside of narrow fair use carve-outs, even if you're not putting it online. "Not getting caught" because you didn't post it online to be found is not the same as "legal".

Ohh, that's cool. Ok, so the one of the problems are that my phone isn't an Android phone. All the supported browsers on the NDEFReader link you gave are Android browsers. How I still read data from an NFC tag on a browser that doesn't originally support something like NDEFReader? The other problem is that my project I'm working on doesn't use HTTPS. It's a localhost server (specifically Node.js). NDEFReader only works on HTTPS, while localhost is HTTP.

That looks like a question for StackOverflow. The answer might be "You can't, until Apple chooses to support this".

As much as it embarrasses me to say this, but my question privilege has been revoked on StackOverflow. It is obviously not meant for new users who are technically new to the internet. I'm trying to fix my questions. Any secondary sites I can go to in the mean time?

"You can't, until Apple chooses to support this"  I believe that is going to be the answer too. Either that, or other browsers that work on Apple devices will allow this kind of interaction in a later update.

@Alex Even permanently ask-suspended accounts can ask one new question once every 6 months. So long as your entire account is not suspended, you'll be able to ask a new question there six months from your suspension date/last question ask date. But yes, it's not a site that is intended to be your first place to ask any question that you come across. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users for further info on that topic.

The primary NFC data read data is the card ID Number.
So each "Amiibo" has an ID number part(or all?) of which is the character (Mario) ID.
A number cannot be copyrighted. So It is perfectly legal to read any unencrypted data stored on the chip.
Use that number in any way you want, without using any copyrighted visual/audio assets to do so.
You can get reader hardware and combine with an ESP32 to utilize either bluetooth or hardwired USB COM port emulation to read the values to your desktop/laptop/phone/tablet... Node.js  client... whatever.
Please note that there are several common frequencies used for NFC communications. Given the low power and short distances almost any frequency could work and meet FCC regulations.

This does not seem to answer the question of how to actually perform the reading in JavaScript.

No, but it does give more detail on the fact about using an amiibo on something other then a Nintendo device. Can you add Javascript code to your answer (if you know how to read a NFC tag using Javascript, of course)

@Alex The code depends on the hardware reader and any driver if required.  The simplest solution is a keyboard HID emulator, the code on any platform is a text input box, and set focus code.
